# AWS ElasticSearch - Match Query Not Working

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, aws-elasticsearch

I have deployed an elastic search instance through AWS` managed ElasticSearch service (version 7.4.2) and having trouble getting "match" queries working. I am playing around with the sample flights dataset and running the following query:

Data:

```
[
    {
        "FlightNum": "HX0WBLI",
        "DestCountry": "IT",
        "OriginWeather": "Damaging Wind",
        "OriginCityName": "Chitose / Tomakomai",
        "AvgTicketPrice": 988.8975638746068,
        "DistanceMiles": 5650.511340218511,
        "FlightDelay": false,
        "DestWeather": "Sunny",
        "Dest": "Verona Villafranca Airport"
    },
    {
        "FlightNum": "VG7H7U4",
        "DestCountry": "IT",
        "OriginWeather": "Cloudy",
        "OriginCityName": "Milan",
        "AvgTicketPrice": 223.66801608639728,
        "DistanceMiles": 78.45850223819446,
        "FlightDelay": false,
        "DestWeather": "Sunny",
        "Dest": "Verona Villafranca Airport"
    },
    {
        "FlightNum": "B3CVVO3",
        "DestCountry": "IT",
        "OriginWeather": "Cloudy",
        "OriginCityName": "Sydney",
        "AvgTicketPrice": 360.41688271717148,
        "DistanceMiles": 10207.122317757072,
        "FlightDelay": false,
        "DestWeather": "Rain",
        "Dest": "Verona Villafranca Airport"
    }
]
```

Query:

```
POST kibana_sample_data_flights/_search
{
   "query": {
       "match":{
           "Dest": "Verona"
       }
    }
}
```

I know there are items with that should partially match but I get an empty result set back. Specifying the full value "Verona Villafranca Airport" yields some results. Is something needs to be enabled to get the query above working?

Also the same query works as expected against a local instance (deployed through docker).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post the mappings of your index ?

Comment: Posted example data.

Comment: The issue could be in the mappings. Post the output of `GET kibana_sample_data_flights/_mapping`

Comment: Hi thanks for following up and answering my question. I believe you are correct, I am going to check the configuration on the index and then confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have not provided your mapping and looking at your question, it seems in your mapping, `Dest` field is defined as `keyword` which isn't analyzed. hence storing `Verona Villafranca Airport` would be stored as it is.

When you use the [match query which is analyzed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) means it uses the same analyzer used to index the field, which would be `keyword` in this case, hence searching for `Verona Villafranca Airport` returns the result as this token present in the inverted index, while searching for `Verona` will not match any token, hence you don't get any result.

Solution: if you want the case insensitive search and want to search on `Verona` or `airport`, then you need to define this `Dest` field as `text` and Elasticsearch uses the `standard` analyzer by default which would automatically lowercase and split the text on whitespace, which would enable above search criteria.

And later on you can use the same `match` query, which you are using and it would work as explained in docs.

**Note on `match` query from doc**

> Returns documents that match a provided text, number, date or boolean
>   value. The provided text is analyzed before matching.

**Tokens generated by standard analyzer**

```
POST /_analyze
{
    "text" : "Verona Villafranca Airport",
    "analyzer" : "standard"
}

{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "verona",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 6,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "villafranca",
            "start_offset": 7,
            "end_offset": 18,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "airport",
            "start_offset": 19,
            "end_offset": 26,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

**Tokens generated by keyword**

```
POST /_analyze

{
    "text" : "Verona Villafranca Airport",
    "analyzer" : "keyword"
}

{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "Verona Villafranca Airport",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 26,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. As you mentioned the property in question is set as keyword and that is why I am seeing this behavior.